# Dimiss Model Presenter by click Button not By swipe

Tags: ios, uikit

I have 2 screen first screen open second screen as model presenter and can close by swipe to bottom and implement UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate and implement didDismiss method .
scenario when swipe this method called  if closed second screen by button (not swipe ) not this method not called